# Firing parent event from childrens' events Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I have a custom UserControl that contains a picture box and a label. I want something to occur any time the user double-clicks anywhere within the boundaries of the UserControl. However, the picture box and the label are blocking double-click events from being captured by the UserControl, so double-clicks will only register when clicking on an area not obscured by the picture box or label.

I have tried forcing double-click events on the picture box and label to call the UserContol's `OnMouseDoubleClick()` function, but it is not working as expected:

```
pictureBox1.MouseDoubleClick += Double_Click;
label1.MouseDoubleClick += Double_Click;
```

...

```
private void Double_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{    
    // Raises UserControl's double-click event      
    this.OnMouseDoubleClick(e); 
}
```

Why would a double-click on the picture box or label not raise the UserControl's OnMouseDoubleClick event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, it works for me:

```
label1.DoubleClick += label1_DoubleClick;
pictureBox1.DoubleClick += pictureBox1_DoubleClick;

private void label1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnDoubleClick(e);
}

private void pictureBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnDoubleClick(e);
}
```

Comment: This is it. I was using `OnMouseDoubleClick` instead of `OnDoubleClick`.